# Writing an array to a CVS file in python

Tags: python, csv

I sincerely apologies if this is an already answered question, I have looked at many resources already and all either make no sense to me or only work in python 2x.

So basically, I have a list which the user appends.

```
print("\nPlease enter all relevant information\n")
A = []
A.append(input("thing: "))
A.append(input("thing2 : "))
A.append(input("etc : "))
```

I want to add all this information into an imported cvs file (which already has several lines) so it would be on a new row and would look something like this

```
thing,thing2,etc
```

This is the code I have for this

```
f  = open('Datafile.csv', "wb")
datafile = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

for item in A:
    datafile.writerow(item)    

f.close()
```

but it doesn't seem to work

error =

```
File "Filepath", line 57, in new
datafile.writerow(item)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Answer (score 2):

`writerow` accepts a list, tuple or dict as its argument, not a string, do this instead:

```
datafile.writerow(A)
```

You're also opening your file in `'wb'` mode, and you want to append to it, use `'a'` instead:

```
f  = open('Datafile.csv', "a")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in A:
    datafile.writerow(item)
```

should just be

```
datafile.writerow(A)
```